# What is Meliodas's TRUE power level

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

Before regaining his true power Meliodas has a power level of 3,750 then he regains his true power having a power level of 32,500 but Meliodas seems like he is much more powerful.
[image]

look at that smirk seems like he's hiding his true power**

Answer (score 4):

Well, his 'normal' Power level would be 32,500. 
With the "Demon Mark" it is at 56,000.

After his revival, his 'normal' power level was at 60,000.
And in is Assault Mode it is at 142,000.

Other numbers aren't known to us at this point, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

If the darkness swallowed him entirely or the demon kind took over his body then he would have a power level of over 200k

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references. Specify specific anime episodes and manga chapters, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Aside of the power levels listed here, there are 2 power levels more listed for him before his power were restored.

4400 with the Demon Mark and 10,300 when going berseker (again, before his powers were restored)

[Meliodas Wikia](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.fandom.com/wiki/Meliodas)